# How to wait in first child's created hook until second child's created hook route query is changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have three components: parent, child1, child2.

I have created() hook in child1, where I change route query:

```
this.$router.replace({
      query: {
        ...vm.$route.query,
        param1: 'var1'
      }
```

I have also created() hook in child2, where I change another query parameter in a same way depending on a query-param1 from the first child. How can I wait until route changing in the first child will complete?

Comment: there is no way to await or control the order or timing of lifecycle hooks.  can you explain why this logic must be split between multiple components?  why can't the parent handle the query replacements by itself?